# My dog keeps pulling out the others eyebrows

Tags: dogs, aggression

I have three German shepherds, they are nine months old and came from the same litter. While I am gone, one of the dogs literally pulls out the other dog's eyebrows. I have tried separating them but they hate it and scream the entire time I'm gone. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Eye brow pulling is the symptom, not the illness.

The illness here sounds like a combination of *boredom* and/or *separation anxiety*. Probably the latter.

GS are an intelligent and energetic breed. When you are home, there is balance because you absorb their interest/energy, when you leave things spiral out of control.

Please, do some googling on separation anxiety and doggie boredom. That really is your problem, fixing that is much better than putting irritants near a dog's eye.

The things I remember reading about separation anxiety:

- exhaust them before you leave the house with a walk or other play
- don't make a big emotional scene when you leave (and come home)
- leave them with a treat filled kong or other similar toy

Answer (score -1):

A stretch but use a q-tip and put something bitter on the eyebrow (like a bitter apple).

But it may be an irritant to the eye so just start with a dab.  Even if you hit an inch above the eye it would get on the other dogs tongue.

Comment: Yeah, be really careful if you try this...

Comment: I would be super careful before i would ever try to put bitter apple on your dog's eyebrow because it is so close to the dog's eye!